# how to compile the java file generated by cup

Tags: java, cup

I downloaded the demo from http://www2.cs.tum.edu/projects/cup/
I got `parser.java` by command:

```
java -jar bin/java-cup-11a.jar cup/parser.cup
```

but when I compile `parser.java` by:

```
javac -classpath lib/java-cup-11a-runtime.jar parser.java
```

the result is:

> ```
> cspro@Think:~/Desktop/template$ javac -classpath lib/*.jar -d .  parser.java
> parser.java:104: cannot find symbol
> symbol  : class Parser
> location: class Example.parser
>       if (args.length==0) new Parser(new Scanner(System.in,sf),sf).parse();
>                               ^
> parser.java:104: java_cup.runtime.Scanner is abstract; cannot be instantiated
>       if (args.length==0) new Parser(new Scanner(System.in,sf),sf).parse();
>                                      ^
> parser.java:105: cannot find symbol
> symbol  : class Parser
> location: class Example.parser
>       else new Parser(new Scanner(new java.io.FileInputStream(args[0]),sf),sf).parse();
>                ^
> parser.java:105: java_cup.runtime.Scanner is abstract; cannot be instantiated
>       else new Parser(new Scanner(new java.io.FileInputStream(args[0]),sf),sf).parse();
>                       ^
> Note: parser.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
> 4 errors
> ```

how to compile the parser.java ?

Comment: What stands out: You say you have the .jar in the dir `bin/` yet you set the classpath to `lib/*.jar`.

Comment: the first .jar contains the cup java class while the second contains classes needed to compile parser.java, they are different